# Is it possible to install KVM On A VMWare virtual machine? If so, what are the steps?

Tags: centos, kvm, vmware, virtualization

I want to understand how to use KVM in CenTOS.  At the moment, all I have is a VMWare ESX 5.x server to use.  Is there a way to get KVM working on a system that is running on VMWare? Essentially, a nested install?

This will not be used for production purposes, only testing/learning.

Comment: Yes it is possible, you have to enable nested virtualisation - http://www.virtuallyghetto.com/2012/08/how-to-enable-nested-esxi-other.html

Comment: @Urlich: Please convert the comment to an answer.

Comment: @Mike B: "install" is misleading most of the time. KVM is just a facility offered by the kernel (accessed through the character device at `/dev/kvm`). CentOS should have the kernel module in the kernel package by default (though it *could* also be compiled-in). What you install is the hypervisor that makes use of KVM (e.g., QEMU).

Answer (score 3):

To allow KVM to function inside a VM do the following;

In esxi 5.5 add the following line to your VM to enable nested virtualization;

```
hypervisor.cpuid.v0 = "FALSE"
```

Steps:
go to "edit settings" ---->"options"---->"Advanced"---> "General"--->"Configuration Parameters"---->"configuration button, select add row and add  the new parameter. `hypervisor.cpuid.v0 = "FALSE"`

Comment: Any chance that something similar could be done on VMware Workstation (12 pro) as well ?